# Count NA Values by Group (Year and month) in several columns in R

Tags: r, datetime, bar-chart, missing-data

I would like to count the number of missing values (`NA`) in each month and year of the time series (columns) and plot a bar chart.
How to extract this information from a data frame?
I need as result a table with the number of missing values (NA) per month each year, for each columns.

```
b <- read.table(text = '        Date  AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE
49 1999-12-15 24.8 21.4 25.6 35.0 17.4
50 1999-12-16   NA  0.6  1.5  6.3  2.5
51 1999-12-17   NA 16.3 20.3  NA 19.2
52 1999-12-18   13  1.6 NA  6.3  0.0
53 1999-12-19   10 36.4 12.5 26.8 24.9
54 1999-12-20   NA  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.0
55 1999-12-21  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
56 1999-12-22  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0')

head(b)
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to be displayed in the bar chart? The total missing? proportion of missing? Other data?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "several columns". Which columns? Can you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: This may not be a proper reproducible example, as all values have the same month and year

Comment: I want the total missing data (NA) in each month of each year for each column. The columns contain the time series data.

Answer (score 2):

You ask two questions, but to address the one in your title, you can count the `NA` values across columns AAA through EEE by year and month in `dplyr` (note the data are slightly changed to include multiple year-month groups):

```
b %>%
  mutate(ym = format(as.Date(Date), "%Y-%m")) %>%
  summarise(NA_count = sum(across(AAA:EEE, ~sum(is.na(.x)))),
            .by = ym)

#        ym NA_count
# 1 1999-01        3
# 2 1999-02        2
# 3 1999-03        0
```

To create a barplot of this, there are several ways. One way in base R is (note, I saved the above data as `plotdat`):

```
barplot(plotdat$NA_count, 
        names.arg = plotdat$ym)
```

[image]

Note I changed your sample data to have multiple year-month groups:

```
b <- read.table(text = '        Date  AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE
49 1999-1-15 24.8 21.4 25.6 35.0 17.4
50 1999-1-16   NA  0.6  1.5  6.3  2.5
51 1999-1-17   NA 16.3 20.3  NA 19.2
52 1999-2-18   13  1.6 NA  6.3  0.0
53 1999-2-19   10 36.4 12.5 26.8 24.9
54 1999-2-20   NA  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.0
55 1999-3-21  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
56 1999-3-22  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the kind data provision given in @jpsmith's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78127984/20002111), I would like to add two approaches:

### 1. Base R

Use `by`; very concise:

```
b$Date = format(as.Date(b$Date), "%Y-%m")
by(b, b$Date, \(x) sum(is.na(x))) |> barplot()
```

or,

### 2. `{collapse}`

for really large data, `collapse::BY` + `rowSums` might be faster

```r
library(collapse)
BY(b, b$Date, \(x) sum(is.na(x))) |> rowSums() |> barplot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to use `tapply` and `mean`,

```
> tapply(b[-1], strftime(b$Date, '%Y-%m'), is.na) |> sapply(mean) |> 
+   barplot(ylab='p. NA', las=1)
```

[image]

or `colMeans`.

```
> tapply(b[-1], strftime(b$Date, '%Y-%m'), is.na) |> sapply(colMeans) |> 
+   barplot(beside=TRUE, ylab='p. NA', leg=names(b[-1]), col=hcl.colors(ncol(b) - 1), las=1)
```

[image]

### Edit

I think it was already answered, but using `tapply` such a table you can get like so:

```
> tapply(b[-1], strftime(b$Date, '%Y-%m'), is.na) |> sapply(colSums)
    1999-01 1999-02 1999-03
AAA       2       1       0
BBB       0       0       0
CCC       0       1       0
DDD       1       0       0
EEE       0       0       0
```

---

*Data:*

Thanks to *@jpsmith*

```
> dput(b)
structure(list(Date = c("1999-1-15", "1999-1-16", "1999-1-17", 
"1999-2-18", "1999-2-19", "1999-2-20", "1999-3-21", "1999-3-22"
), AAA = c(24.8, NA, NA, 13, 10, NA, 0.2, 0), BBB = c(21.4, 0.6, 
16.3, 1.6, 36.4, 0, 0, 0), CCC = c(25.6, 1.5, 20.3, NA, 12.5, 
0, 0, 0), DDD = c(35, 6.3, NA, 6.3, 26.8, 0.2, 0, 0), EEE = c(17.4, 
2.5, 19.2, 0, 24.9, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("49", 
"50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56"))
```

Comment: I need a table with Column name and number of missing values (NA) per month each year: